# tcpreplay error: Libpcap versions < 0.7.2 are not supported

Tags: libpcap, tcpreplay

while configuring tcpreplay by

```
  root@sdn1-PC:/home/cdcju/tcpreplay-4.1.1# ./configure
```

i am getting error saying

```
  checking for libpcap version... configure: error: Libpcap versions < 0.7.2 are not supported
  Please upgrade to version 0.7.2 or better
```

while i have already installed libpcap-1.7.4 using instruction given in http://www.question-defense.com/2010/07/07/install-newest-libpcap-version-on-centos-linux

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
./configure --with-libpcap=<directory that you installed libpcap into>
```

Comment: when i am typing dpkg -L libpcap-1.7.4 it is showing dpkg-query: package 'libpcap' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

Comment: the above command is required if you download the source directly, as per instructions in the link you provided. If you want to install _libpcap_ sources as a package that can be seen by _dpkg_, you will want to use a package manager. Your link suggests you are using Centos, in which case you run `yum install libcap-devel`. If you use Debian or one of its variants, run `apt-get install libpcap-dev`. Then you can run `./configure` with no other parameters.